# log negociated protocol and cipher suite when using https module in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, ssl, logging, https

### Introduction

I use the native `https` module of node.js to make a get request on a website.
The website only give the good document when you use some specific cipher and tls version.

A quick draft of my code is like this

```js
var ciphers = ["RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384","RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA"].join(":");

const options = {
    host:'www.example.mg',
    port:'443',
    minVersion: 'TLSv1.2',
    ciphers:ciphers,
    path : '/',
    agent: agent,
    headers: {
        'Host': 'www.example.mg',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
    }

}

https.get(options,(res) =>{
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    res.on('data', (d) => {

      process.stdout.write(res.headers["content-encoding"] == "gzip" ? zlib.gunzipSync(d) : d);
    });

  }).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
```

### The point of the question

I want to know what protocol version and cipher were finally negociated during the handshake. I want to log those informations like in the screenshoot but that was done in Java HttpClient. Now i need to do it in Node.js.

[image: Desired result]

I already tried using `NODE_DEBUG='tls,https'` but the informations logged were not enough

[image: What i got]